# Renpy, исключение при попытке собрать билд на Android (renpy.loader.transfn)

Tags: python, android, json, apk, renpy

Допустим, есть json файл, лежащий в ./resources и названный "string.json". Тогда парсинг этого файла можно будет реализовать следующим образом:

```
label start:
    $ import json
    $ f = open(renpy.loader.transfn("resources/string.json"))
    $ text = json.load(f)
```

На ПК и на Android эмуляторе такой сценарий будет отлично работать, однако когда я собираю билд и запускаю его на телефоне, то вылетает исключение:
[image: Исключение при начале игры с android устройства]

Возможно, это как-то связано с архитектурой APK-пакета, или еще какими-то нюансами, но в документации я не нашла решения этой проблемы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для разрешения исключения можно использовать метод renpy.file

То есть:

```
label start:
    $ import json
    $ f = renpy.file("resources/string.json")
    $ text = json.load(f)
```